# Count distinct to find records with different values in a column table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple question: How can I use having Count(Distinct) in SQL (Oracle to be exact) to return only the rows where there are 2 column with same record but 1 column with different record.

Example

```
CA_ID   BA_ID   SA_ID       
----    -----   --------    
CA1     BA1     SA1 
CA1     BA2     SA1 
CA1     BA2     SA2
CA1     BA3     SA1 
CA2     BA4     SA3
CA2     BA4     SA4
CA2     BA5     SA4
CA3     BA6     SA6
```

In that example, i'd like to create a query that shows 1 same CA_ID and SA_ID, but has different BA_ID. The query's result should show like this

```
CA_ID   BA_ID   SA_ID       
----    -----   --------    
CA1     BA1     SA1 
CA1     BA2     SA1 
CA1     BA3     SA1 
CA2     BA4     SA4
CA2     BA5     SA4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  CA_ID   
       ,BA_ID   
       ,SA_ID
from   (select  t.*
               ,count(distinct BA_ID)  over(partition by CA_ID, SA_ID) as dcount
        from    t
       ) t
where  dcount > 1
```

| CA_ID | BA_ID | SA_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CA1 | BA1 | SA1 |
| CA1 | BA2 | SA1 |
| CA1 | BA3 | SA1 |
| CA2 | BA4 | SA4 |
| CA2 | BA5 | SA4 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I-ih6NaG?hide=14)

Comment: can u explain what partition is for?

Comment: @NashuhaTasbir it runs the `window function` separately on each chosen group. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin001.htm

Answer (score -1):

We can try an aggregation approach to find the matching `CA_ID` and `SA_ID` values:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CA_ID, SA_ID
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY CA_ID, SA_ID
    HAVING MIN(BA_ID) <> MAX(BA_ID)
)

SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM cte t2
    WHERE t2.CA_ID = t1.CA_ID AND
          t2.SA_ID = t1.SA_ID
);
```

Comment: its not working (still gets all data) ...